# Remove item from iCloud - "Cannot disable syncing on a unsynced item."

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, icloud

At the beginng of my app, i want to delete a few items from iCloud permanently.

But in any case, the console tells me "Cannot disable syncing on a unsynced item."

```
dispatch_async(globalQueue, ^(void) {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSError *error = nil;
    // Move the file.
    BOOL success = [fileManager setUbiquitous:NO itemAtURL:removeItemURL
                               destinationURL:dest error:&error];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        if (! success) {
            NSLog(@"MEGA ERROR %@", [error userInfo]);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the file you want to remove from ubiquity is not there. That's what the error message says. Did you check (via NSMetadataQuery) if the file is in the iCloud?

Comment: For the first time I didn't see incorrect URL to my file, but you are right, the method couldn't find the file because I forgot the "Documents" folder in the URL of the param "itemAtURL:"

Thanks a lot